# Encrypting Whole Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encryption, sql-server-2008-express

I need to encrypt whole databse, not any specific column in the database. This should be done in SQL 2008 or in SQL 2008 Express edition

If any one can, do favour for this

Comment: SQL Server supports this via the [Transparent Data Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) feature. If you have a *specific* question about how to set it up, I think serverfault.com would be a better place to ask anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Check this might help you to achive your task :

[Understanding Transparent Data Encryption](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Transparent_Data_Encryption_p1.aspx)

[Using Transparent Data Encryption in SQL Server 2008](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/using-transparent-data-encryption-in-sql-server-2008/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) might do the trick, where you store your data files on an encrypted share.  I've never tried it, but I would expect it to work - but some quick Googling shows that people have had problems with it.  So if you try this, proceed with caution.

Comment: I am not sure that TrueCrypt is his answer - even though I am a long time user. TrueCrypt will create an ecrypted volume, on which he can place his databse, but he has to mount it to access it. If that is accespatable than I can say that I have used TrueCrypt for at least 5 years on both Windows & Linux and have never had a single problem. It is arguably the best product of its kind which there is.

Comment: Yes, without more requirements, it's hard to say whether or not this would work, since it would mean mounting a drive and therefore leaving the data accessible while the drive is mounted.  But if the requirement is just to have the data physically encrypted in case the hard disk is stolen, then TrueCrypt may just be all they need.